# How to display model parameters in a form text area

Tags: ruby-on-rails, forms, email, templates, variables

I'm using a form to create custom email templates in my rails app but I want to be able to customise parts of the email body using parameters from my model.

Here is the code for my mailto link:

```
<a href="mailto:<%= @contact.email_address %>?subject=<%= @tracker.title %> <%= @email.template.subject %>&Body=Hey <%= @contact.first_name %>,%0D%0A %0D%0A <%= @email.template.body %> %0D%0A Thanks, Cat">Send template</a>
```

So in the form text area for @email.template.body which generates the body for an email I want to be able to write something like:

```
We'd love to run a feature on <%= @goal.title %> for our magazine.
```

I want the @goal.title code to display it's value from my model - in this case a business name for example. However it simply displays <%= @goal.title %> rather than pulling in the place name.

I hope that makes sense. Does anyone have any suggestions for how I can make the code display correctly or know of a text editor that allows me to create custom variables which might work in this case?

Comment: You should probally just use a form instead of a link.

Comment: Thanks @max - if I was to use a form, is there a way to get the parameters such as goal.title to display the correct content?

Comment: Its a bit unclear what you're actually after here. Are you looking to create user editedable mail templates where they can insert placeholders? Or is the template a programmer concern and you just want to interpolate variables into it?

Comment: If its the former you'll want to use a different templating engine then ERB which is a lot more limited (and can do a lot less damage). Handlebars/mustache for example.

Comment: Thanks @max - it's for an app that only I would access, so I don't need to worry about users adding javascript etc. I'll check out handlebars - do you know any good guides for getting started?

Answer (score 0):

If you fully trust the input you can use inline rendering in the controller:

```
result = render_to_string(inline: the_template_string)
```

Rendering in other contexts like the model can be done but you'll have to setup the binding and do a lot more of the nitty gritty work - see the [ERB docs](https://docs.ruby-lang.org/en/3.2.0/ERB.html) for examples.

I can't stress enough that this should be done with great care. ERB can run any arbitrary Ruby code including running shell commands.

Comment: Thank you again @max - that is working perfectly, you came to the rescue again!